# paragraphs spacing

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I have paragraphs, I want them to look like in the image (without blank line in between but with an indent)

[image]

when I use "\\" a blanc line appears in the pdf file 
so, how to procede for that ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section*{Résumé}

Notre projet consiste à la .................., toutes deux connectées à la même base de données.

\par Nous souhaitons à travers .............. le temps nécessaire à les accomplir.

\end{document}
```

this is how it looks now

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a MWE so that we can help you?

Comment: `\usepackage{indentfirst}` makes an indent after captions

Comment: As usual, your not providing any help by posting a MWE :-(

Comment: I put a code and a figure, I tried double backslashes and \par but same result with both

Comment: Running your example, I do not get a blank line

Comment: the default for `article` is no extra space between paragraphs, so you must be doing something that you aren't showing us.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you were right I found it but I don't know how to escape it, I have in a section above {\setlength{\parskip}{12pt} so how to reset default I need this in above sections

Comment: i don't believe that `\parskip` is set globally, and you have an opening brace before your setting, so when a matching closing brace is encountered, the setting should revert to the default.  however, since the affected section occurs immediately after `\begin{document}` it is likely that the new setting is in the preamble.  move it to somewhere *after* your résumé -- the manual says it can be reset anywhere.

Comment: your example shows no `\\ ` but in the text you say you use `\\ ` _never_ use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, it generates a warning about badnes10000 and very poor output.

Comment: @HindDev please fix your example, the image that you show is not generated by the code that you post, this is simply misleading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the advice, I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose two solutions: one uses the `\paragraph` sectioning command, the other is based on a convenient version of the `description` environment and is obtained as a `resume` environment (might be not a very good naming choice). As I don't know if you want it to use a sans font, I gave examples of both:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english,francais]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{resume}{%
\sffamily
\newlength\resindent\settowidth{\resindent}{\bfseries Résumé}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline, leftmargin=0pt, listparindent=\resindent, font=\sffamily}
\description%
\item[Résumé]\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\par
}%
{\enddescription}

\newcommand\Dotsfor[1]{%
\def\mydotfill{\xleaders\hbox to0.25em{\hfil.\hfil}\hfill}\makebox[#1]{\leavevmode\mydotfill}}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Résumé}\mbox{}\par

Notre projet consiste à la \Dotsfor{2cm}, toutes deux connectées à la même base de données.

\par Nous souhaitons à travers \Dotsfor{2cm} le temps nécessaire à les accomplir.
\bigskip
\begin{resume}
Notre projet consiste à la \Dotsfor{2cm}, toutes deux connectées à la même base de données.

\par Nous souhaitons à travers \Dotsfor{2cm} le temps nécessaire à les accomplir.
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

[image]